# Can't resolve 'src/index.js'

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have webpack and it show entry error:

*ERROR in multi @babel/polyfill src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/index.js' in 'F:\webpack\webpack-st\src'
 @ multi @babel/polyfill src/index.js entry[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq7Z3.png)

Here's my folder structure:

[image: structure]

And webpack code that seems to be wrong:

```
context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
entry: {
    entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "src/index.js"],
},
```

I tried to change paths of context and entry but nothing happened except error

Comment: You have set your context to "src", you don't need "src/index.js", just do "./index.js"

Comment: Tried. Nothing changed

Comment: I just did as @noitse said and it worked

Comment: Glad to help. Will add an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your context to `src`, you don't need `src/index.js`. Just do `./index.js` as entry base has been set to `src`.